# NullPointerException when access to array in class

Tags: java, android, arrays, class, nullpointerexception

I am new to this forum and Java. The code below compiles but when I try enter a value to a variable I get NullPointerException. What is wrong?

```
class output_harm
{
    public int[] timestamp;
    public int[] state;

    public output_harm(){
        timestamp = new int[8];
        state = new int[8];
    }
}

output_harm[][] outputs =  new output_harm[7][6];   

outputs[0][0].state[0] = 0; //java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: array Initialization doesn't mean it contains any value. All the values in array are `null` in this case. populate it first before accessing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem**
output_harm[][] outputs =  new output_harm[7][6];

This is just to initialize an array.
When you call constructor output_harm() then only it will do initialization.
state = new int[8]; here state is initialized in constructor and lead to NullPointerException.

**Solution:**
First you need to initialize an object for each **output_harm**(if you need total array to be initialized)

```
output_harm[][] outputs =  new output_harm[7][6];   
    for(int i=0;i<7;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<6;j++){
            outputs[i][j] = new output_harm();
        }
    }

    outputs[0][0].state[0] = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Doing `output_harm[][] outputs =  new output_harm[7][6]` without initialize the values, all values will be set to default, which is `null`

You need to add:

```
outputs[0][0]=new output_harm();
```

then you can do:

```
outputs[0][0].state[0] = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

In line

```
outputs[0][0].state[0] = 0; //java.lang.NullPointerException
```

your `outputs[0][0]` is null so you can not perform any operation on null so this is the root cause of NPE.

Please be sure that you create that object before that line so simply paste before sth like this:

`outputs[0][0] = new output_harm();`

Comment: Calling the constructor requires the `new` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

in your line

```
output_harm[][] outputs =  new output_harm[7][6];
```

you have only initialized your array, the array doesn't contain any value till now.

and, after that you called

```
outputs[0][0].state[0] = 0;
```

which leads you to the `NullPointerException`.

After array initialization, it contains default values (*for your array-type [`output_harm`] it will be `null`*) and you called a variable on `null`, which throws `NullPointerException`.

So, first you have to initialize your array index which you are using, in your case, do

```
outputs[0][0] = new output_harm();
```

then `outputs[0][0].state[0] = 0;`

Answer (score 1):

Just a pointer for you to work on.

```
  output_harm[][] outputs =  new output_harm[7][6];   
  outputs[0][0] =  new output_harm();
  outputs[0][0].state[0] =  0;
  outputs[0][0].state[1] =  1;
```

Comment: Now it is OK. Do I need to create each object in loop or can I create all objects in one line?

Comment: You will have to create each object in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Defining Array means that now `output_harm` is `not null`. But

```
output_harm[][] outputs =  new output_harm[7][6];   

outputs[0][0].state[0] = 0; //java.lang.NullPointerException
```

is accsessing the first index which is `null` yet . so it will be `nullPointerException`